# How do I show that $\int_\gamma e^{z+1/z}dz = 2\pi i \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n!)(n+1)!} $?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I'm not sure how exactly to approach this problem. I believe it has something to do with the Laurent Series of the integrand based on the factorial terms in the summation, but I'm not sure exactly how to get there.

Comment: A hint as to where to start or a reference source would be more than enough help!

Comment: What is $\gamma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\exp(z+1/z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{z^{-m}}{m!}
=\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{n-m}}{n!m!}.$$
If one needed to find the residue at $z=0$ you need to pull out
the coefficient of $z^{-1}$, so look at the terms where $m=n+1$.